# Many DB queries for string representation of model object

Tags: django, django-models

I have this models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Airport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - {1} - {2}".format(self.city, self.city.country, self.name)

class Tour(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tour_from = models.ForeignKey(Airport)
    tour_to = models.ForeignKey(Airport)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

For string representation of `Airport` Django sends many requests to DB:

> 302.06 ms (591 queries including 586 similar and 586 duplicates )

Queries screenshot:
[image]

At `tour/create` page I have a ModelForm for creating a tour and Django sends these queries for displaying form.

**forms.py:**

```
class TourCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tour
        fields = ['title', 'tour_from', 'tour_to']
```

views.py:

```
class DashboardTourCreate(CreateView):
    model = Tour
    template_name = "dashboard/tour/create.html"
    form_class = TourCreateForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardTourCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page_name'] = ['tour', 'tour-index']
        context['page_title'] = "Create Tour"
        return context
```

How I can reduce queries count?

Comment: can you please add your ModelForm and view's code from where you server that request.

Comment: @Shakil Sure. The question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Root Cause

```py
def __str__(self):
    return "{0} - {1} - {2}".format(self.city, self.city.country, self.name)
```

When the `tour_to` and `tour_from` fields are rendered as `<option>` in the `<select>` widget the `Airport.__str__` method is called. Because `Airport.__str__` has `self.city.county` and both of these are `ForeignKey`'s, the Django ORM issues a query to grab the airports city and the citys country.

And it does this for every single `Airport` that is an `<option>` which means the problem will get progressively worse the more `Airport`'s that are added.

## Solution

Leverage `select_related`[1]. `select_related` will tell the Django ORM to pull in the related fields `('city', 'county')` whenever it grabs an `Airport`.

```py
class TourCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tour
        fields = ['title', 'tour_from', 'tour_to']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['tour_from'].queryset = Airport.objects.select_related(
            'city__country',
        )

        self.fields['tour_to'].queryset = Airport.objects.select_related(
            'city__country',
        )
```

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Thanks, dear Scott. Does Django make two queries for two fields?  May I create a variable for these same queries and assign to the field's Queryset?

Comment: I've tested it locally and it works for me. Can you update the models/forms/views?

Answer (score 0):

As f-string is a string literal expressions evaluated at run time [link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), this might be faster that other string format but i am not fully sure. I am expecting following modification may reduce the over all time.

```
class Airport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city} - {self.city.country} - {self.name}"
```

Comment: That was for python 3.6. I have to use python 3.5. I can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by adding `Queryset` to `forms.py`:

```
class TourCreateForm(BaseForm):
    airports = Airport.objects.select_related('city', 'city__country').all()

    tour_from = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=airports)
    tour_to = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=airports)
```

But I think this is not correct!